# Return List from multiple search in C#

Tags: c#

I have TextBox where users can input many numbers (1 per line).

Then, I'm querying a Child Table which has those numbers.

Those numbers are ForeignKeys from Primary Table.

Primary Table - tblOrders

Child Table - tblOrderItems (ForeignKey is OrderID)

```
public class OrderItems
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataC { get; set; }
    public int Item { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<OrderItems> LoadItems()
{
    List<OrderItems> list = new List<OrderItems>();
    string[] textArray = TxtOrder.Text.Split(new string[] { ronment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var text in textArray.Distinct())
    {
        var ctx = new DbContext();
        var query = (from p in ctx.tblOrderItems.AsQueryable()
                     join m in ctx.tblOrders on p.RegistID equals m.RegistID
                     where m.Order.Contains(text)
                     select new OrderItems
                     {
                         ID = p.RegistTID,
                         Order = m.Order,
                         Status = p.Status,
                         DataC = m.DataC,
                         Item = p.Item
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
        list.Add(query);
    }
    return list;
}
```

The problem: Querying like this in the Primary Key, I get correct values because I only get 1 record per item added in TxtOrder Textbox.

But I'm querying tblOrderItems and the tblOrderItems has many records related to 1 record in tblOrders and I can't get them all to my DataGridView.

Comment: Why `m.Order.Contains(text)`? Why not `m.Order == text`? If you can do that then you could take it one step further `textArray.Contains(m.Order)`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help! I need change FirstOrDefault() with something that gives me all records not only the first one! If I erase FirstOrDefault() I'll get error in list.Add(query) --> Cannot convert Generic List to OrderItems...

Comment: aren't you explicitly grabbing only 1 right now with `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Remove the `FirstOrDefault` and Try `list.AddRange(query)`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the items instead of the item, you need to:

Use `ToList` instead of `FirstOrDefault` and `AddRange` instead of `Add`.